# Packaging the Qt 5.7 Virtual keyboard example on Surface Pro tablet

Tags: c++, qt, windows-10, qt5.7, qtvirtualkeyboard

I have run the [Qt Virtual Keyboard example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-basic-example.html) successfully with Qt 5.7 in Qt Creator on Windows 10 desktop, but if I try to run the same exe on Windows Surface Pro (running on Windows 10) by including all necessary dlls and plugins, I am just getting the QML lineedits, but the keyboard is not popping up and the application just hangs. The exe isn't telling what else it requires to make it run.

The package I created is here:

[image: directory listing]

Comment: Have you tried this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html ?

Comment: @ramtheconqueror....Thanks,but I tried the same, didn't work out yet....May be the way to package QML applications is different or something. :-|

Comment: Perhaps you need to build the virtual keyboard module yourself, and pass `CONFIG+=disable-desktop` to `qmake`. It could be that the keyboard thinks it should be using a dedicated window for the input panel, whereas it probably should be integrating the input panel into the Qt Quick scene.